# Declaring Table Variable using Existing Table Schema in Sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to declare a Table Variable in my stored procedure using existing tables schema.

I have a Table, say `TableA`, which has about 30 columns. 
I want to declare a Table Variable using the same columns just as we declare a Temporary Table.

For instance,
I can declare a Temporary Table using the schema like this:

```
SELECT TOP 0 * INTO #Temp_TableA FROM TableA
```

Can I similarly declare a Table Variable???

Comment: Why does not suit temporary table?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7981800/create-tablevariable-based-on-an-existing-database-table

Answer (score 1):

From [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/7ad699eb-a3a7-4b92-bb35-6be468c65532/sql-server-select-into-temp-table-variables?forum=sqlgetstarted): 
No, table variable is a variable as name suggests so you need to declare it before you can use it like all other T-SQL variables and you need to use `INSERT INTO`

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE(
ID INT NOT NULL,
Data varchar(30) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO @MyTable
SELECT ID, data
From <table>
```

You can also use a temporary table in your stored procedure. Just add to the beginning of stored procedure this code:

```
if object_id('tempdb..#TableA') is not null drop table #TableA
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a CTE for this purpose:

```
; with CTE as (SELECT TOP 0* FROM TableA)
SELECT * FROM CTE
```

The only thing to remember is CTE can only be used in the next line after the initialization. So for example, the following won't work-

```
; with CTE as (SELECT TOP 0* FROM TableA)
SELECT * FROM TableA
SELECT * FROM CTE
```

because here CTE will become invalid.

Answer (score 0):

DECLARE A Table Variable having same as SCHEMA of your table first and then INSERT INTO syntax as mentioned by Megatron.

If you are planning to use inside a stored procedure, then use CTE and don't forget to mention ; befire CTE declareation  and insert into CTE variable from your table.