# how to set something for null value in a parameter

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, null

Im using following procedure in one of my applications

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[FeeRecordSelect]
@GRNo varchar(4),
@PaymentModeId numeric(2) output
as
begin
SELECT @PaymentModeId = Students.PaymentModeId FROM Students where Students.GRNo = @GRNo
end 
GO
```

my question is: i want to select 1 in @PaymentModeId if I get no result for @GRNo

I Already have tried this

```
create procedure [dbo].[FeeRecordSelect10]
@GRNo varchar(4),
@PaymentModeId numeric(2) output
as
begin
SELECT @PaymentModeId = isnull(Students.PaymentModeId, 1) FROM Students where Students.GRNo = @GRNo
end 
GO
```

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?  Please retag with the appropriate one.

Comment: Might want to look [at this SO article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4823880/sql-server-select-into-variable) and also consider checking the value of @paymentModeID after the insert for null, then setting it to 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@PaymentModeId will only be set if there is at least one row returned by the select.

Put

```
Set @PaymentModeId = 1
```

before the select to set the default value to 1. Now if there are no rows selected, it will still return 1.

Edit:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[FeeRecordSelect]
@GRNo varchar(4),
@PaymentModeId numeric(2) output
as
begin

Set @PaymentModeId = 1    

SELECT @PaymentModeId = Students.PaymentModeId FROM Students where Students.GRNo = @GRNo
end 
GO
```

Comment: I request you to please edit your asnwer in my coding.. so that i can understand exactly where you want me to use set @PaymentModeId = 1

Comment: I don't know how to do it more clearly than that. Do you not see the edit at the bottom of my post?

Comment: Thanks Moose it is working. but I wish there could have been something like isnull.

Comment: I nevertheless have to accept your answer because it is anyhow working

Comment: If it works, upvoting and accepting the answer would be appreciated. the isnull will work if there is a row to return null, but since there  is not, the assignment is never made.

Answer (score 2):

The reason IsNull() doesn't work is because the resultset doesn't contain any rows.

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[FeeRecordSelect]  
@GRNo varchar(4),  
@PaymentModeId numeric(2) output
as  
begin  
set @PaymentModeId = isnull((select Students.PaymentModeId FROM Students where Students.GRNo = @GRNo), 1)
end   
GO
```

Comment: sorry your code is not working. however what Moos suggested me is working fine

Comment: I guess output params cannot have defaults...  I updated my answer to use IsNull properly in this situation.