# ASP.net is it possible to read existing Access database

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ms-access

I'm very new to asp.net and practically know nothing about it. I'm asking this strictly out of curiosity:

I have an existing Access database with multiple tables with id links. I'm wondering if asp.net can read from it? if so, what is the correct path to achieve this?

I'm only familiar with MVC framework when it comes down to web dev. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You don't need MVC in this task at all. Use [ADO.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16452694/1849444)

Comment: Is this very similar to ASP.net?

Answer (score 0):

If you create MVC normal project, database content is into `App Data` folder, so if you have database just copy `.db` file into AppData folder, then run nugget package console in your visual studio, click `Tools --> Library Package Manager --> Package Manager Console` and write:

```
Add-Migration FirstMigration     (press enter)
```

Note: if you have error here just tip these:

```
Add-Migration FirstMigration -Force
```

and Finally do

```
Update-database      (press enter)
```

Expecting it works that achieve that you want, regards