# Assign values to multiple variables from one select statement MS SQL

Tags: sql-server, variables

The code below works. Can this be improved?

```
declare @rlcstallname varchar(50), @rlcsalesdept varchar(50), @rlcpath varchar(50)

set @rlcstallname   = (select stallname from sometable)
set @rlcsalesdept   = (select salesdept from sometable)
set @rlcpath        = (select [path] from sometable)
```

I need to know how to get the three values I store into the variables using only one select statement; I find executing 3 select statements excessive.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server SELECT INTO @variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4823880/sql-server-select-into-variable)

Answer (score 10):

```
SELECT
    @rlcstallname = stallname,
    @rlcsalesdept = salesdept,
    @rlcpath = [path]
FROM sometable
```

Comment: Thank you for this specific answer, wewesthemenace