# Store variable SQL Statement into a JSON variable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to store a `FOR JSON AUTO` output in a variable.

But I want to use a variable select statement.

Something like this:

```
SET @SQLString = 'SELECT ID, Name FROM ' + @TableName + ' ';

SET @Body = (
   @SQLString + 'FOR JSON AUTO'
);
```

Comment: [SQL Server SELECT INTO @variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4823880/sql-server-select-into-variable) ??

Comment: Should be able to do something like https://dbfiddle.uk/jX2avhmt - be careful to avoid SQL injection when making it dynamic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = 'select * from sys.objects'

declare @forJsonSql nvarchar(max) = concat('select @json = (',@sql, ' for json auto)')

--print @forJsonSql

declare @json nvarchar(max)
exec sp_executesql @forJsonSql, N'@json nvarchar(max) output', @json=@json output

select @json
```